# create evenly spaced and vertically centered nav bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I apply `position:absolute` styling to elements and they move horizontally to the right. I need them to not do that...

```css
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Logo</a></li>
    <li><a>What</a></li>
    <li><a>How</a></li>
    <li><a>Why</a></li>
    <li><a>Supporters</a></li>
    <li><a>Blog</a></li>
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

or if there is an entirely better way to make a vertically aligned and evenly spaced out nav bar, I'm open to starting fresh.

Comment: `float:left` and some `margin` should do the trick

Comment: float left on the "nav a"? Because that didn't work. And what do you mean some margin?

Comment: Do you want something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3b3f65zz/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep it really clean and simple.

You're already using the HTML5 `nav` element, which is semantically meaningful. So you don't need to use a `ul`.

You're also using flexbox, which makes linear alignment easy.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;   /* horizontal alignment */
  align-items: center;              /* vertical alignment */
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */
nav {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
a {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a>Logo</a>
  <a>What</a>
  <a>How</a>
  <a>Why</a>
  <a>Supporters</a>
  <a>Blog</a>
  <a>Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Oh wow. I haven't coded in quite some time so I'm relearning things. HTML5 just came out last time I was learning. I was looking at source code from Apple and they used a UL and LIs in their nav so I thought that was what was standard. Your code is simpler and works perfectly fine. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can make your list item stretch at equal sizes (i.e. justified) like this:

```css
nav ul {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: separate;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  width: 1%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Logo</a></li>
    <li><a>What</a></li>
    <li><a>How</a></li>
    <li><a>Why</a></li>
    <li><a>Supporters</a></li>
    <li><a>Blog</a></li>
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding padding left or right, also margin left or right to `<li>` may work